# background video hd quality html5

Tags: html, video, background

i'm having problems to play video on HD quality using html or anyother way..

http://www.baked.ag

the problem is that when you compress to .ogg .mp4 the video looses quality..

has anyone found an solution to play an HD video this way?

any help is appreciated

Comment: every recompression (and especially codec change) will lose quality. but you can control the AMOUNT of loss by tweaking the transcoder settings.

Comment: but there is no way that i can play it on HD quality?

Comment: @MarcB is absolutely right. And if you increase the bitrate in your transcoder settings you will preserve the quality, but will also have a too heavy video file in your hands, which will produce a bottleneck when seen over the net. If you are making a demo for local use go for it, but if you are planning to deploy your artwork in the net you may wish to consider losing some quality for gaining "speed". Good luck!

Comment: `hd quality` is a buzzword. hd what? resolution? anything that's at least 1366x768 qualifies as "hd" in north america but video purists will get upset if you try to force them to watch your lowres "hd" video.

Comment: we decided to use VIMEO HD instead an HTML5..

Comment: but thanks anyway..
oh.. and now.. we changed the way we show the video.. it's not the main "frame" at the site!
hahaha tks again